# Cognos Report Author and Conditional Style to Hide or Display Columns

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi

I have two columns of the Crosstabs.

CAR 1                 CAR 2
  1                    2
  0                    8

Now, I have it going fine using the Conditional Style Advanced option to NOT To SHOW CAR1 in the resulting Report, if CAR 2 is selected from the prompt page.

I'm using the following but it works only for selecting one Checkbox at a time from the Car Selection.

If I select CAR1 and CAR2 from the Checkboxes, None of the CARS listing is showing instead of showing both CARS counts.

Here is the syntax I'm using within the Conditional Style: It is not working.

ParamValue('car_param')  NOT IN ('1','2')
and in the Advanced Style: Box Type: NONE

So, when the selection is 1 and 2, the listing should show. If the selection is 3,4, the CAR 1 and CAR 2 listing shouldn't show.

Please help if you could.

Thx so much for your time.

Comment: Did you check your car_param values?
Add simple text box that shows values of your param.

Comment: Yes. I'm using ParamValue('car_param')  and it is showing me 1, 2 as the values. So, I have the above logic when ParamValue('car_param') NOT IN ('1','2') and in the Advanced Style: Box Type: NONE

Comment: Alexey, Would you let me know how you would add the text box that shows the values?

Comment: Create usual textbox and use a parameter value in expression

Comment: And returning to first question.
Read about Style Variables in user guide. Unfortunately you did something that is I can't fix or understand in text format.

Comment: Ok here is the problem. I have two Style Variable: (ParamValue('car_param')  not in ('1')) then 
('Y')
else
('N')

Comment: Ok here is the problem. I have two Style Variable: (ParamValue('car_param')  not in ('car-1')) then 
('Y')
else
('N') and the second one (ParamValue('car_param')  not in ('car-2')) then 
('Y')
else
('N') Now, I have assigned the column (source type data item label) to isCAR1 by selecting the column, navigating to Conditional Explorer and Assigning Yes. Same thing for CAR-2 Column and Assigned the Variable isCAR2 (Conditional Explorer: Yes) But when I select CAR-1 in the prompt page, the  ParamValue('car_param') shows 1 for CAR-1 selection and 2 for CAR-2 selection.

Comment: When I select CAR-1, the CAR-1 Column shows perfectly (the only Column) but when I choose CAR-1 and CAR-2 (with Use Value for the check box as 1,2, no column shows at all.. Thx Alexey for your time.

Comment: Problem resolved: I got it working: ParamDisplayValue('car_param') CONTAINS ('CAR-1')  in Conditional Style. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was that a multi-select checkbox returns a comma-separated string in the form '1,2,3,4'

Consider your expression:

```
ParamValue('car_param') NOT IN ('1','2')
```

If 1 is selected the string passed in is just '1' and the expression works:

```
'1' NOT IN ('1','2') //Evaluates false
```

If 1 and 2 are selected, the string passed in is '1','2' and the expression no longer works:

```
'1','2' NOT IN ('1','2') //Evaluates true
```

The solution is to reverse the logic of the expression:

```
'1' NOT IN ParamValue('car_param') AND '2' NOT IN ParamValue('car_param')
```

Passing in 1 and 2 now results in this:

```
'1' NOT IN ('1','2') AND '2' NOT IN ('1','2') //Evaluates false
```